# Sort list and eliminate duplicates in XSLT?

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, duplicates, xslt-2.0

Starting point is an XML-list like

```
<attributes>
        <para role="tocmain1"/>
        <para role="tocmain1"/>
        <other style="fix"/>
        <other style="fix"/>
        <para role="tocmain2"/>
        <para role="tocmain2"/>
        <para role="tocmain2"/>
        <para role="tocmain3"/>
        <para role="tocmain3"/>
        <para language="de"/>
        <para language="de"/>
        <para role="tocmain3"/>
</attributes>
```

I would like to reduce the occurrences of each element + attribute + value instance to just one occurrence.

Like this:

```
<attributes>
     <other style="fix"/>
     <para language="de"/>
     <para role="tocmain1"/>
     <para role="tocmain2"/>
     <para role="tocmain3"/>    
</attributes>`
```

So far I have only succeeded to order the list alphabetically. All my attempts to reduce the list have been in vain so far.

That is what I have right now:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <attributes>
        <xsl:for-each select="attributes/node()">               
            <xsl:sort select="name()" order="ascending"/>           
            <xsl:sort select="@*" order="ascending"/>                   
            <xsl:choose> 
                <xsl:when test="name() = name(preceding::*[1]) and self::node()/@* = preceding::*/@*"/> 
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </attributes>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, based on proposal of Daniel Haley I found an answer which works for my question.

I'm using now two xsl one after the other:

1. XSL which gives an unordered list without duplicates

   ```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
       <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
       <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>       
       <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
           <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
           </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>      
        <xsl:template match="/*">
            <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
               <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="@*">
                   <xsl:sort select="@*"/>
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]"/>
               </xsl:for-each-group>
           </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:template>       
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
2. XSL which orders the list:

   ```
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="2.0">
       <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
       <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
       <xsl:template match="/">
           <attributes>
               <xsl:for-each select="attributes/node()">                 
                   <xsl:sort select="name()" order="ascending"/> 
                   <xsl:sort select="name(@*)" order="ascending"/>                   
                   <xsl:sort select="@*" order="ascending"/>                  
                   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>                  
               </xsl:for-each>   
           </attributes>
       </xsl:template>           
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
3. Result as requested:

   ```
   <attributes>
       <other style="fix"/>
       <para language="de"/>
       <para role="tocmain1"/>
       <para role="tocmain2"/>
       <para role="tocmain3"/>    
   </attributes>
   ```

Thank you for helping me find the answer and sorry for misleading example XML! If someone knows how to combine the two steps into one script: you are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `xsl:for-each-group` and `xsl:apply-templates` to the first node in the group. This should make it easy to add any additional transformation that might need to happen in the future.

**XML Input** (modified to show correct sorting)

```
<attributes>
    <para role="tocmain3"/>
    <para role="tocmain2"/>
    <para role="tocmain1"/>
    <para role="tocmain3"/>
    <para role="tocmain1"/>
    <para role="tocmain2"/>
    <para role="tocmain1"/>
    <para role="tocmain1"/>
    <para role="tocmain2"/>
    <para role="tocmain3"/>
    <para role="tocmain2"/>
    <para role="tocmain2"/>
    <para role="tocmain2"/>
    <para role="tocmain3"/>
    <para role="tocmain2"/>
    <para role="tocmain3"/>
    <para role="tocmain2"/>
    <para role="tocmain3"/>
    <para role="tocmain2"/>
    <para role="tocmain3"/>
</attributes>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="@role">
        <xsl:sort select="@role"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]"/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<attributes>
   <para role="tocmain1"/>
   <para role="tocmain2"/>
   <para role="tocmain3"/>
</attributes>
```

Comment: I should have mentionend explicitely that the list differs in elements, attributes and values. I edited my list on this behalve. All your attempts which use @role won't work. That's why I tried to use */@*. I need to delete duplicates on basis of same element + same attribute + same value.

Answer (score 0):

Your XSLT generates your requested XML modulo some formatting issues that can be resolved with `xsl:output` and `xsl:strip-space`.  Also, you might leverage `distinct-values()` to streamline your code:

**Your XML input document,**

```
<attributes>
  <para role="tocmain1"/>
  <para role="tocmain1"/>
  <para role="tocmain1"/>
  <para role="tocmain1"/>
  <para role="tocmain2"/>
  <para role="tocmain2"/>
  <para role="tocmain2"/>
  <para role="tocmain2"/>
  <para role="tocmain2"/>
  <para role="tocmain3"/>
  <para role="tocmain3"/>
  <para role="tocmain3"/>
</attributes>
```

**given to this streamlined XSLT,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/attributes">
    <attributes>
      <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(para/@role)">
        <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending"/>
        <para role="{.}"/>
      </xsl:for-each> 
    </attributes>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**will produce this XML output document,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<attributes>
   <para role="tocmain1"/>
   <para role="tocmain2"/>
   <para role="tocmain3"/>
</attributes>
```

**as requested.**